# How to not copy ".svn" folders from left to right

Tags: winmerge

I love WinMerge, and I can get it to not display SVN folders in the compare, however how can I configure it **not to copy** the ".svn" folders from left to right when I want to bring a folder from the left to the right without copying it file by file?

PS I am using WinMerge 2.12.4.0

Comment: Sorry that I did not understand you correctly first. You mean you don't want to copy the ".svn" *sub*folders (recursively) when copying from left to right, right? I don't think there's a build-in solution for your problem, perhaps you should file a feature request on http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=13216

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Doc Browns link I just found the following, sadly really old, bug report:

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1731181&group_id=13216&atid=363216